# Programming for Symbian devices

Tags: mobile, symbian

I didn't know where to post this so i came here. Anyway I'm wondering is it worth even targeting Symbian phones? Especially since nokia don't even want anything to do with it anymore.

Do symbian phones get the latest updates for chrome and firefox mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are still lots of old phones areond, but almost no new phones are sold. If you know Symbian then you can develop on it for existing customers, but there is no point starting to learn the language